# MDX percentage calculation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to caculate the percentage and add it to my cube measure.

Basicaly i am trying to calculate the percentage of sales 
Week
01 to 02 Waiting Times
03 to 04 Waiting Times
|
|
99 to 100 Waiting Times

The formula to calculate the percentage is 
SUM(sum of all the amount up to 17 to 18 Waiting Times) 
/
SUM(Sum of amount for the all the Waiting Times)

Can some one help me with the mdx to achive SUM(sum of all the amount up to 17 to 18 weeks) .

I tried the below. But the problem is , the numarator [Waiting Times].[Wait].&[17 To 18 Weeks] is just giving me the amount for that week. I need the sum of amount up to 17 to 18  [Waiting Times].

```
CREATE
MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Percent of Performance] AS
CASE
WHEN
IsEmpty([Measures].[Patients])
THEN NULL
ELSE
(
[Waiting Times].[Wait].&[17 To 18 Weeks]
,[Measures].[Patients]
)
/
(
[Waiting Times].[Wait].[All]
,[Measures].[Amount]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all members upto a certain member then you can use the range operator `:` with null i.e. `null:[x]`

So applying to your script:

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Percent of Performance] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsEmpty([Measures].[Patients])
     ,NULL
     ,Divide
      (
        (
          NULL : [Waiting Times].[Wait].[17 To 18 Weeks]
         ,[Measures].[Patients]
        )
       ,(
          [Waiting Times].[Wait].[All]
         ,[Measures].[Amount]
        )
      )
    ) ;
```

If you try the following do you still get NULL, if so it means that your condition `IsEmpty([Measures].[Patients])` is true?

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Percent of Performance] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsEmpty([Measures].[Patients])
     ,NULL
     ,1
    ) ;
```

Comment: I tried the above , i was able to execute the measure. I gives me null when i pull this on to my cube browser it gives NULL

Comment: @Ranjitha - maybe it is not getting beyond the first option in `IIF` - please try the experimental script I've added

Comment: i think i had some permission issue. I have sorted it out and the code works perfect. Thank you.